# Query partial match for tags and another attribute in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to return all results whereby
-  the title (string)
- or any of the tags (array) 
associated with this object have a partial match with the query.

Currently I have the following (Postgres) but its not returning any results.

```
 where(":q = ANY (tags) OR 'title' iLIKE :q", q: "%#{query}%")
```

relevant part of the Trip table

```
create_table "trips", force: true do |t|
 t.string   "title"
 t.string   "tags",              default: [], array: true
```

Typical record would:

```
Trip.create(title: 'Test', tags: ['Edinburgh', 'London'])

if query = 'edi' or 'te'
```

should return above record.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `:q` both in `iLIKE` and `= ANY (tags)`, maybe this would work better:

```
where(":q = ANY (tags) OR 'title' iLIKE :iq", q: query, iq: "%#{query}%")
```

---

Also `ANY` is not `ILIKE`, to create the equivalent see [here](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Question-with-combining-ANY-with-ilike-td1910482.html):

> For the benefit of future searches I used:
>
> ```sql
> create function reverse_ilike(text, text) RETURNS boolean AS 'select $2 ilike $1;' LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE RETURNS NULL ON NULL
> ```
>
> INPUT;
>
> ```
> create operator ~~*^ (PROCEDURE = reverse_ilike, LEFTARG = text, RIGHTARG = text);
> ```
>
> Best,

Which should (I did not test this) enable you to do:

```
where(":q ~~*^ ANY (tags) OR 'title' iLIKE :iq", q: query, iq: "%#{query}%")
```

---

**Edit**

Also, it seems that you have a typo - you check the input query is `iLike` the *string* `'title'` instead of the *column* `title` - the query should be:

```
where(":q ~~*^ ANY (tags) OR title iLIKE :iq", q: query, iq: "%#{query}%")
```

Comment: thanks, i gave this a try, its still not returning any results.

Comment: Please give some more information about your table, what you expect to find etc...

Comment: Thanks, I gave this a shot but it still doesnt seem to work, I shall keep on digging.  
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: unknown ~~*^ character varying

Comment: did you run the `create function` and the `create operator` in PG console?

Comment: if i switch the matcher from ~~*^ to ~~* then it works, and does a match on the FULL tag, but will not return partial matches. Additionally the OR operator has stopped working.

Comment: Go into the psql and run the two `create` command I pointed to before trying to use the `~~*^` operator - I've tested it, it should work. Also, see my **edit** - you also have a typo in your query.

Comment: superb! thanks so much for your help Uri. Very helpful